# Looking for a better way to handle update request in python

Tags: python, flask

I create a `flask` application for my web server and one of the endpoint is to update `contact` information. One contact has many attributes such as `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` etc. I declare below method to handle update request on the contact:

```
def update_contact_with_form(contact_id, id=None, username=None, first_name=None, last_name=None, email=None, password=None, phone=None, user_status=None):
    session = Session()
    try:
        contact = session.query(DBContact).filter(DBContact.id == contact_id).one()
        if username != None:
            contact.username = username
        if first_name != None:
            contact.first_name = first_name
        ...

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        session.close()
    return abort(400, 'failed to update')
```

The above code works fine but what I don't like is to check each value against `None`. Is there a better way to update the instance without checking each attribute?

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```py
def update_contact_with_form(contact_id, **kwargs):
    session = Session()
    try:
        contact = session.query(DBContact).filter(DBContact.id == contact_id).one()
        for k, v in kwargs:
            if v is not None:
                contact.__setattr__(k, v)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        session.close()
    return abort(400, 'failed to update')
```